# How to insert data in mysql using javascript based on the input value

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

```js
function message() {
    $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","halcondentalclinic");
    var s = document.getElementById('edit_otherValue');
    if (s=="Crown") {
    <?php  
      $try18s=="Crown";
      $db="INSERT INTO tooth1(treatment)VALUES('$try18s')";
      $db_run=mysqli_query($connection,$db);
    ?>
  }
 }
```

```html
<input type=text name=edit_otherValue id=edit_otherValue value="" />
<button onclick="message()" type="submit" name="treatmenthistoryupdatebtn" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

How to insert data in MySQL using  javascript based on the input value 
I'm just a beginner in javascript.

Comment: you cannot use vanilla javascript to insert data into database. You can instead use nodejs which is a javascript compiler which supports all kinds of databases.

Comment: no worries! here's a link to get you started with database in nodejs if you're really into javascript. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Like said in comment, you can't do it with "simple" javascript.

The function "message" you link is write in PHP and to call it with your JS code you will need to perform a ajax call.

There is great resources online:

- like [this one](https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/4286486-build-web-apps-with-reactjs) for reactjs
- or [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/php/) for php
- and [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp)